# In Java 9+ with Scala, how to make a Cleanable that can be triggered by `System.gc()`

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-11, scala-2.13

Considering the following example in Scala 2.13.12 & Java 11:

```
class CleanableSpike extends AnyFunSpec {

  import CleanableSpike._

  it("triggered by GC") {

    var v = Dummy(inc)
    v = null

    System.gc()

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    assert(count == 1)
  }
}

object CleanableSpike {

  val jvmCleaner = Cleaner.create()

  @transient var count = 0

  val inc = () => count += 1

  case class Dummy(fn: () => Unit) extends AutoCloseable {

    final private val cleanable = jvmCleaner.register(
      this,
      { () =>
        println("\ncleaned\n")
        fn()
      }
    )

    override def close(): Unit = cleanable.clean()
  }
}
```

When the test is executed, it gave the following error:

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: 0 did not equal 1
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.newAssertionFailedException(Assertions.scala:472)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.newAssertionFailedException$(Assertions.scala:471)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions$.newAssertionFailedException(Assertions.scala:1231)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper.macroAssert(Assertions.scala:1295)
    at com.tribbloids.spookystuff.lifespan.CleanableSpike.$anonfun$new$1(CleanableSpike.scala:19)
```

Clearly, the cleanup function was not triggered, ironically, if I replace the Cleaner implementation with the now-obsolete `finalize()` function, the test will pass.

What could go wrong here, and what implementation should I use to ensure that the new implementation can have the same capability (namely, to be triggered by System.gc())?

Comment: As said at the other question, you are unlikely to get answers if you require the reader to understand internals of Scala. How is a `case class` implemented? I don’t know, but it looks like you are trying to invoke a method `fn()` on the very object that is supposed to be garbage collected at cleanup time. This can’t work. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html#:~:text=it%20is%20important,to%20the%20object) says: “*it is important that the object implementing the cleaning action does not hold references to the object*”

Comment: @Holger actually the reference is single-directional: Dummy hold reference to fn, but not vice versa. I'll rewrite the question using Java shortly.

Comment: Then, there’s the issue with the memory visibility. `count` is accessed by different threads…